# How should I approach to catch UDP packets server creation

Tags: c#, winforms, udp, listener

I am working on my application and one of the components that I need is the server that would listen on port 9494 for UDP packets.
Then I would have to parse these packets.

I have never done this before; could you please point me to the right direction so I could write the "listener"?

For TCP I can do `this.listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);` ; what aout the UDP ?

Comment: I have not done port programming. But other wise, its just a subscriber publisher design model. Google it up.

Comment: See the TcpListener example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx

Comment: @Kevin, TcpListener for UDP packets?

Comment: D'oh!  Next time I'll actually read before commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx

All you have to do is create a UdpClient and call Receive or BeginReceive. UDP is "connectionless" so it is much simpler to work with - you simply get entire UDP messages at once when you receive.